# jQuery not working with form inside a InfoWindow

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, google-maps, infowindow

I use JQuery to handle all my form submits, and they are all working fine. But I can't seem to get it working with a form that is inside a dynamically generated (Googlemap's marker) InfoWindow. Should I use it in a different way? Maybe with `$(document).on` to capture the submit?

This is the code to catch the form submit:

```
$(function() {
$('#new_marker').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post($("#new_marker").attr("action"), $("#new_marker").serialize(), function(data) {
        var json = myParseJSON( data );
        if( json.status=="success" ) {
            location.href = site_root+'map/modify_marker/'+json.marker_id;
        } else {
            new Messi( json.msg, {title: 'Oops...', titleClass: 'anim error', buttons: [{id: 0, label: 'Fechar', val: 'X'}]});
        }
    }).fail( function() { general_error(); } );
    return false;
});
});
```

As I've said, a code just like this for all my other forms, but not for the `new_marker` form that is inside an InfoWindow. It just basically posts the form to action without even aknowledging the Jquery code.

This is the code I use to load contents to the InfowWindow:

```
function newmarker_infowindow_content(lat, long, infowindow) {
    $.ajax({
    url: site_root +'map/newmarker_infowindow/' + lat +'/' +long,
    success: function(data){
        infowindow.setContent(data);
        processInLineLabels();
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since form isn't available on page load...you will need to delegate the submit handler to an asset that is permanent in page. Closest would be element the map is being inserted in but could also use `document`.

```
$('#MapDivID').on('submit', '#new_marker', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     /* do ajax*/
})
```

Read more about event delegation in [**jQuery on() docs**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: I've been trying to use `on` ever since I posted this. No luck. I've tried with `document`, placing the code both in my main `site.js` and inside the loaded InfoWindow along the HTML. Nothing. The code is just ignored.

Comment: inspect the form in live html view in console... does it have the right ID?

Comment: It worked! But only works if I wrap the `on` it with a `$(function() {...`.

Comment: well that goes without saying...should always do that